# Implementing rotate left using AND, NOT, and ADD operations

Tags: assembly

I'm implementing a 16-bit bit shifter to rotate bits to the left by **r**.  I only have access to the `AND`, `NOT` and `ADD` operations.  There are 3 condition codes: *negative*, *zero* and *positive*, which are set when you use any of these operations.

#### This is my approach:

1. `AND` the number with `1000 0000 0000 0000` to set condition codes to *positive* if the most significant bit is `1`.
2. `ADD` the number with itself. This shifts bits to the left by one.
3. If the MSB was `1`, `ADD` `1` to the result.
4. Loop through steps (1)-(3) **r** times.

Are there any other efficient ways I can do this?

Comment: Hmm, very interesting, but probably an SO question.

Comment: Both logical shift left and arithmetic shift left set the new LSB to 0.  Your method is a rotate left (or circular shift).

Comment: Or a Code Golf & Programming Puzzles question.  http://codegolf.stackexchange.com

Comment: @RD01 Yes sorry. This is what I want.

Comment: @Orbling I've flagged it for "off topic -- belongs on SO"

Comment: http://www.hackersdelight.org/

Comment: I think your logic is sound and efficient.  You have not described the conditional operations or how the condition code for step 1 is preserved to be used in step 3 without being modified by the condition code from step 2 (likely trivial when the conditional execution is understood/described).

Comment: @fdart17 - This came _from_ programmers, perhaps you want to flag on your question there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is homework, I'll help you think about it.

```
2 * 2 = 4
4 * 2 = 8
8 * 2 = 16

0010 * 0010 = 00100
0100 * 0010 = 01000
1000 * 0010 = 10000
```

A left shift is a [some unknown] operation.  That [some unknown] operation can be implemented using AND, NOT and ADD by doing...

Comment: Looking back at the comments, it looks like he's actually looking to do a rotate-left operation and named it incorrectly.  His algorithm confirms that too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some x86 code to get you started:

```
; I'm assuming the number you want to rotate is in ax
; I'm assuming the number of bits to rotate is in cx
loop_start:
  add cx, -1                  ; Can only use add, so add -1
  jo loop_end                 ; If cx is < 0
  mov bx, ax                  ; Copy ax into bx
  add ax, ax                  ; shift ax left 1 bit
  and bx, 1000000000000000b   ; Test the msb of bx
  jz loop_start               ; if the msb is zero, jump
  add ax, 1                   ; if the msb is one, add one to ax
  jmp loop_start              ; Loop
loop_end:
```